# How do I remove a stuck Facebook event from the Lock Screen calendar?

Tags: calendars, facebook, lock-screen

I got invited to a Facebook event which last 3 months, and I didn't decline before  it started. Now its stuck on my lock screen and I cant get it off. I have since declined the event and removed myself from the guest list, restarted my phone and changed the detailed lockscreen from calendar to another and back again. any ideas?

Comment: You could remove Facebook events from your calendar for the time being if that's an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to the people hub then accounts and manually re synced to Facebook. It does this periodically but not sure how often as it was 3-4 days since the previous one.